# Redirect all sub-domain to parent domain except one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I am able to access my website with random sub-domains like this

```
abcd.theonlytutorials.com
abc.theonlytutorials.com
etc.theonlytutorials.com/otherpage/otherpage
```

I have one real sub-domain where my blog is

```
blog.theonlytutorials.com
```

Is there any possible way to redirect all my fake sub-domains to root domain except the 'blog' one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules that you may already have in there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.theonlytutorials\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(blog|www)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://theonlytutorials.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may look into following URL:
[Redirect sub domain to main domain](http://www.kingscooty.com/blog/redirect-a-subdomain-to-a-main-domain-using-htaccess/)